# show that " . " has an neural element

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

let $" . "$ be an associative, and a multiplicative law in E having ($\forall y \in E$) ($\exists x \in E$) $y=axa$ ( $a$ is an element of $E$)

how can I proceed to find the the neutral element? I thought about starting with the fact ($\exists b \in E$) such as $aba=a$ but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: So... $a$ is a single fixed element? Or what? If it's not fixed, why wasn't it quantified over?

Answer (score 3):

Since $aba=a$, one candidate of a (left) identity is $ab$.

Verify that it's indeed a left identity ($aby=y$ for all $y$).

Similarly, $ba$ is a right identity.

Thus, $ab=(ab)(ba)=ba$ is the identity element.

Comment: For arbitrary $y$ there exists an $x$ such that $aby = abaxa = axa = y$. Similarly, $yba = axaba = axa = y$. Finally, $ab=abba=ba$. I'm not seeing where von Eitzen's counterexample goes wrong.

Comment: @Mathy $a\notin E$ in his example.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.

Let $A$ be the free group on two generators $a,b$.
We have a monoid homomorphism $f\colon B\to\Bbb Z$ induced by $a\mapsto 0$, $b\mapsto 1$.
Let $E=f^{-1}(\Bbb Z_{>0})$. Then $E$ fulfils the condition of the problem statement: Given $y\in E$, we find $x:=a^{-1}ya^{-1}\in A$, for which clearly $axa=y$. As $f(x)=f(y)$, we have $x\in E$ as desired. 
However, $E$ has no neutral element because $f(ez)=f(e)+f(z)>f(z)$ for all $z$, no matter what $e$ we pick.

Comment: I think I got the problem: $a\notin E$ in your example. It's nice, however.